# Confirmation for updated Entity in Datastore

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, datastore

I know this is basic question, but I cannot find answer anywhere and it is not possible for me to do it by trial and error. I have Android app and want to update entity in Datastore by +1. I send request to Google app engine, where I get entity, update it +1, put entity to Datastore and send confirmation to Android application with `response.getWriter().println("OK");`, everything work great, but what if Android app lose connection after sending request, Google app engine will get request to update entity +1, but confirmation doesnt hit Android app. Will be entity updated +1 even if I dont get `"OK"` confirmation in Android app? If yes, what is the best practice to prevent this?

Thanks in advance

Code:

```
public class Score extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        String update = req.getParameter("update");  //update = 1
        resp.getWriter().println(add(Integer.valueOf(update)));
    }

    public String add(int update) {
        // ...
        Entity entity = datastore.get(key);
        int score = ((Number) entity.getProperty("Score")).intValue();
        score += update;
        entity.setProperty("Score", score);
        datastore.put(entity);
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity will be updated as soon as you tell the Datastore to do it, regardless of whether the confirmation reaches the client.

I am not sure why you want to prevent this (it's a very unusual requirement), but the solution will require two calls: one to prepare the change and the second to commit it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so the only possibility to "prevent" it, is send request to Google app engine to get entity, in Android app make +1 and send another request to put entity to datastore? Or is there any "faster" way like `if(response.getWriter().println("OK")!=fail){datastore.put(entity);}`

Comment: There is a gap in time between print("OK") and when this OK reaches the client. This gap is much larger than between datastore.put(entity) and print("OK"). I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.